# row_number() but only increment value after a specific value in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Query: <strike>`SELECT (row_number() OVER ()) as grp, * from tbl`</strike>

Edit: the rows below are returned by a pgrouting shortest path function and it does have a sequence.

```
seq grp   id
1    1      8
2    2      3
3    3      2
4    4      null
5    5      324
6    6      82
7    7      89
8    8      null
9    9      1
10   10     2
11   11     90
12   12     null
```

How do I make it so that the `grp` column is only incremented after a `null` value on `id` - and also keep the same order of rows

```
seq grp   id 
1    1      8
2    1      3
3    1      2
4    1      null
5    2      324
6    2      82
7    2      89
8    2      null
9    3      1
10   3      2
11   3      90
12   3      null
```

Comment: "and also keep the same order of rows" - there is no order. You haven't specified an `ORDER BY` clause, the system is free to return rows in any order that is most convenient to it at that time. And there's no obvious way to add an `ORDER BY` given just the sample data you've currently provided.

Comment: You need to order first to preserve this order...

Comment: SQL does not know which order is used, see: [What is the default order of records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql)  (Which is about MySQL, but it also applies to PostgreSQL)

Comment: Hi all, I changed question and you guys are right, it does have a sequence column to order by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=15a823750e43a62eda3a151bd12f49be)

Using a cumulative `SUM` aggregation is a possible approach:

```
SELECT
    SUM(                                       -- 2
       CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  -- 1
    ) OVER (ORDER BY seq) as grp,
    id
FROM mytable
```

1. If the current (ordered!) value is `NULL`, then make it `1`, else `0`. Now you got a bunch of zeros, delimited by a 1 at each `NULL` record. If you'd summerize these values cumulatively, at each `NULL` record, the sum increased.
2. Execution of the cumulative `SUM()` using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)

This yields:

```
0   8
0   3
0   2
1   null
1   324
1   82
1   89
2   null
2   1
2   2
2   90
3   null
```

As you can see, the groups start with the `NULL` records, but you are expecting to end it.

This can be achieved by adding another window function: `LAG()`, which moves the records to the next row:

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN next_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) OVER (ORDER BY seq) as grp,
    id
FROM (
    SELECT
        LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY seq) as next_id,
        seq,
        id
    FROM mytable
) s
```

The result is your expected one:

```
1   8
1   3
1   2
1   null
2   324
2   82
2   89
2   null
3   1
3   2
3   90
3   null
```

Comment: `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` would be better than having to use lag. You'll then also need to add 1 if you want the id to start from 1. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d6569bc70e3369596f3e9938b5b4c6e2

Comment: Good idea! I forgot this option!